# I'm trying to display rows in SQL Server with php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlsrv

the response i get after making connection and running the query is "resource(4) of type (SQL Server Connection)"

```
<?php    
$serverName = "xx.xx.xx.xx";   
$uid = "sa";     
$pwd = "xxxxxxxxxx";    
$databaseName = "courierdb";   

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                              
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                              
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);   

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

var_dump($conn);


/* Execute the query. */    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.AwbDomestics";     
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) {

        echo "row:<br>"; var_dump($row); echo "<br><br>";

    }
    else {
        echo "<br/>No Results were found."; 
    }

}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn); 
?>
```

how do i select all the rows in the database without this "resource(4) of type (SQL Server Connection). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt))` test should be around the loop, not inside it.

```
if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "row:<br>"; var_dump($row); echo "<br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br/>No Results were found."; 
    }
}
```

To check for errors from the query, you should check if `$stmt` is `FALSE`, not `$conn`. So change

```
if ($conn == false)
```

to

```
if (!$stmt)
```

Comment: i still get resource(4) of type (SQL Server Connection)

Comment: That's the expected output of `var_dump($conn);` why do you think that's a problem?

Comment: i get no rows returned  from the  query. i think the query is failing somewhere and i can't seem to find it. i var_dump($row) i get nothing. but when i var_dump($stmt) it returns a resource.

Comment: the table had empty rows all this while. the table was truncated without my knowledge. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this script. Using `sqlsrv_has_rows()` is not necessary. Use [sqlsrv_fetch_array()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch-array?view=sql-server-2017) or [sqlsrv_fetch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch?view=sql-server-2017)/[sqlsrv_get_field()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-get-field?view=sql-server-2017) to retrieve data.

```
<?php
/* Warnings */
sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 1);

/* Connection */
$serverName = "xx.xx.xx.xx";   
$uid = "sa";     
$pwd = "xxxxxxxxxx";    
$databaseName = "courierdb";   
$connectionInfo = array(
    "UID" => $uid,                              
    "PWD" => $pwd,                              
    "Database" => $databaseName
);   
$conn = sqlsrv_connect(
    $serverName, 
    $connectionInfo
);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Execute the query with sqlsrv_fetch_array(). */    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.AwbDomestics";     
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //print_r($row, true);
    foreach($row as $field => $value) {
        echo $field.": ".$value." ";
    }
    echo "\n";  
}

/* Execute the query with sqlsrv_fetch()/sqlsrv_get_field(). */    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.AwbDomestics";     
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$fc = sqlsrv_num_fields($stmt);
while (sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $fc; $i++) {
        echo sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR))." ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}

/* End */
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);  
sqlsrv_close($conn); 
?>
```

Comment: i still get resource(4) of type (SQL Server Connection)

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine Yes, sqlsrv_connect() and sqlsrv_query() return resource or false (on error). sqlsrv_fetch_array() returns an array, null if there are no more rows to retrieve and false on error.

Comment: the sqlsrv_fetch_array() is not returning anything and there are rows in the table.when i var_dump($row); nothing is displayed.

Comment: Strange. Is there any output before while()?

Comment: i get this when i var_dump($stmt) resource(3) of type (SQL Server Statement)
No output.

Comment: the table had empty rows all this while. the table was truncated without my knowledge. thanks for the help